# standard test videos for video processing

Tags: matlab, video-processing

So.. In image processing, [lena](http://ndevilla.free.fr/lena/) is the standard image for testing out algorithms in the research community. Similarly.. Are there any standard videos for testing out MATLAB codes for video processing?

Comment: it was short sighted of playboy not to shoot a video of Lena as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are also commonly used video sequences – though to a degree it depends on the type of video algorithm you're developing (reflected in the level of motion, type of motion, resolution etc.) and the file type you want (e.g. YUV, compressed).

As a starting point, `foreman.yuv`, `Carphone.yuv`, `akiyo.yuv`, `bus.yuv`, `coastguard.yuv`, `flower.yuv`.

For example googling the above turned up a reasonable looking repositories at the following:

- [YUV Video Sequences – ASU](http://trace.eas.asu.edu/yuv/)
- [Derf's Test Video Collection at xiph.org](http://media.xiph.org/video/derf/)

Lately, the Blender clips [Big Buck Bunny](https://peach.blender.org/), [Tears of Steel](https://mango.blender.org/) and [Sintel](https://durian.blender.org/) have been more frequently used, as they are available in HD and 4K resolutions as well as in stereo 3D.

Answer (score 3):

/Too long for a comment/

I came across some builtin sample/demo files in a matlab blog post: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/01/10/colormap-manipulations/

Apparently the files `clown` and `cameraman` are builtin and you can just load them using `load clown` or `load cameraman`.

It depends however on the installed toolboxes: clown is from the wavelet toolbox and cameraman from the image processing toolbox. They both can be found on the matlab path of course, so you can always look around there. You'll also there find the files: autumn, board, canoe, cell, circbw, circuit,...

EDIT: also: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1376-finding-example-images-in-the-distribution

But for video I personally haven't seen anything like that in matlab

EDIT2:
I stand corrected: in the vision toolbox, there are some example videos, in the visiondemos subdirectory of the toolbox. Just search for avi files on the matlab install directory